# Load an Image from other Jframe,Java

Tags: java, image, swing, load, jframe

I made a project and when it runs,it crops two images and make a screenshot for each of them,from two different Jframes. I want to have these two screenshots in one other different jframe. How can I load these two screenshots?Any idea?Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Your question boiled down to its essential is this: how can I pass on object (here  an Image or ImageIcon) from one object (one GUI) to another (the other GUI object).

The solution is the same as in any other non-GUI, non-Swing program: you pass a reference from one object to another, often via a method parameter or a constructor parameter.

i.e.,

```
class Gui2 {

  private Icon icon;

  public Gui2(Icon icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
    // add icon to JLabel if desired
  }
}
```

For more specific advice, please give more specifics about your problem and your code.
As an aside, it is most unusual for a JFrame to show other JFrames. Usually if secondary windows are displayed from a parent window, the secondary windows are dialogs, such as JDialogs.

Comment: I edit my post,and I put a part of my code.I hope to be more useful.Thank you.

Comment: @user2933161: no, not yet. We have no idea about any other aspect of your program. Please try to sit in our shoes and imagine how we can help you given the limited information so far presented.